# looping through dynamic table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, logic

How to loop through dynamic database table?

I have a situation where I need to loop through a table with `n` rows while looping it adds some rows in the same table and it should loop until all old and newly added rows are not iterated to the end.

For example I have created prototype

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
con = None

try:
    con = lite.connect('dynamiciteration.db')

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tbl (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, roll text)")
    cur.execute("insert into tbl (roll) values ('1')")
    con.commit()
except lite.Error, e:
    print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
    sys.exit(1) 

cur.execute("select roll from tbl")
rows = cur.fetchall()
print len(rows)
j = 0

for row in rows:
    #print 'iteration '+str(j)
    j = j + 1
    try:
        cur.execute("insert into tbl (roll) values ('"+str(j)+"')")
        con.commit()
        if(j < 100):
            cur.execute("select roll from tbl")
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            print len(rows)
    except lite.Error, e:
        print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
        sys.exit(1)
```

where I added a termination condition as `if (j < 100)`. The problem is the `rows` database object is not updated as other variables, otherwise it would work well.

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-binding the `rows` list to a new result set, and the `for` loop doesn't ever see such a rebind. It's as if you did:

```
somelist = [1, 2, 3]
for i in somelist:
    somelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    print i
```

This would only ever print the numbers 1, 2 and 3.

You could use a `while` loop:

```
index = 0
while index < len(rows)
    row = rows[index]
    index += 1
```

Now `rows` is dereferenced each time the `while` condition is checked, as well as when `row` is set each iteration.

But you have to be very careful about your ordering to make sure than new rows are added to the *end* of the list result by the database.